# comparing a value with next value in a column

Tags: r

I have a data set of the following form:

```
Interval | Count    |   criteria    
0        0               0                             
0        1               0                            
0        2               0                             
0        3               0                             
1        4               1                             
1        5               2                             
1        6               3                            
1        7               4                             
2        8               1                          
2        9               2       
3        10              3
```

I need to compare the values in the Interval. I first need to create a new variable to store the values. If the value in the Interval is the same as the next value,  then the new variable should have blanks. If the Interval value is not the same as the next value, then it should return criteria/Count. Output should be like this:

```
Interval | Count    |   criteria  |  N

0        0               0                             
0        1               0                            
0        2               0                             
0        3               0       0                      
1        4               1                             
1        5               2                             
1        6               3                            
1        7               4       0.5714                     
2        8               1                          
2        9               2       0.2222 

3        10              3
```

Here is my code:

```
fid$N<-''
for (i in 1:length(fid$Interval))
{
if (fid$Interval[i] != fid$Interval[i+1]) 
 fid$N<-fid$criteria/fid$Count
 else 
 fid$N<-''
 }
```

and this is the error I am getting.

> Error in if (fid$Interval[i] != fid$Interval[i + 1]) fid$N <- fid$criteria/fid$Count else fid$N <- "" :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

To add that, there is no missing value in the data set.

I would appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: For the last value there is no `i + 1` value available hence you get the error. Your loop should go from `1:(length(fid$Interval) - 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a loop for this since most of the R functions are vectorized. Here is a way to do this in base R, `dplyr` and `data.table` without using a loop.

```
#Base R 
transform(df, N = ifelse(Interval != c(tail(Interval, -1), NA), criteria/Count, NA))

#dplyr
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(N = if_else(Interval != lead(Interval), criteria/Count, NA_real_))

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, N:= fifelse(Interval != shift(Interval, type = 'lead'), criteria/Count, NA_real_)]
```

All of which return :

```
#   Interval Count criteria         N
#1         0     0        0        NA
#2         0     1        0        NA
#3         0     2        0        NA
#4         0     3        0 0.0000000
#5         1     4        1        NA
#6         1     5        2        NA
#7         1     6        3        NA
#8         1     7        4 0.5714286
#9         2     8        1        NA
#10        2     9        2 0.2222222
#11        3    10        3        NA
```

I return `NA` instead of blank value because if we return blank value the entire column becomes of type character and the numbers are no longer useful. In the answer you can replace `NA` with `''` to get a blank value.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Interval = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L), Count = 0:10, criteria = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: Just one more question, what if I also want to return a value for the very last entry. In my example the last one is Interval 3, and I want it to return 3/10 rather than NA.

Comment: Use : `df %>% mutate(N = if_else(Interval != lead(Interval) | row_number() == n(), criteria/Count, NA_real_))`